# What pkg creates symlink from /lib/libncurses.so.5 to /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.5?

Tags: ncurses, lib

what package would setup a symlink from "/lib/libncurses.so.5" to the actual library, /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.5?

This is a programming question, because I'm trying to compile/link a program that wants to use -lncurses, and I strongly prefer not to have to kludge the makefile with references to architecture specific libncurses.

Yes, I know I could create my own symlink in /lib, but it sure seems like "apt-get install" of *something* should have done it for me.

/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.5 was installed with: apt-get install libncurses5 and/or libncurses5-dev.

I've seen a few symlinks from /lib/foo.so (for various values of "foo") to /lib//foo.so on various Linux systems, so I know this is not a completely uncommon practice.

In this case, I'm on a Pinebook (ARM64) running Ubuntu.

thanks,
Stan

Answer (score 0):

The place to look is the `ldconfig` configuration.  [This thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=914618) might give you some insight.